# Find difference between groupby values for specific categories in Pandas

Tags: pandas, group-by

I'd like to find the difference between values in a Pandas groupby dataframe, but for specific column values. I've read multiple posts about using the `diff` command, but that applies to subsequent rows regardless of groupings.

In the dataframe below (it's a dictionary), the dataframe has columns for user id `trial_id`, a condition `placebovstreatment`, a moderator variable `expbin`, and a value.

I want to calculate the difference between values within users, but only if they have values for certain condition categories.

For instance, user 1 has values of

```
correct_placebo_baseline    10.000
correct_treatment   21.000
```

The difference is 11.

User 2 has values of

```
0   22.000
correct_placebo_baseline 8.688
```

The difference is roughly 14.

User 1 has a difference between column categories `correct_placebo_baseline` and `correct_treatment`. User 2 has a difference between, `correct_placebo_baseline` and category '0'.

How do I calculate only if a user has both a `correct_placebo_baseline` and a 'correct_treatment' groupings? Or, alternatively, how do you create columns where the differences are specific per group per user?

The formula could create columns `difference from baseline for correct placebo` and 'difference from baseline for 0' for each trial_id.

The challenge is that some users don't have a baseline score. Some users have a baseline score but nothing else. I need difference values only if they have both.

I tried to find a way to run a function when groupby categories meet certain criteria, but couldn't.

Thanks for any help and let me know if I can make this question easier to answer.

```
{'trial_id': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 3, 6: 3, 7: 4, 8: 4, 9: 5},
 'placebovstreatment': {0: '0',
  1: 'correct_placebo_baseline',
  2: 'correct_treatment',
  3: '0',
  4: 'correct_placebo_baseline',
  5: 'correct_placebo_baseline',
  6: 'incorrect_placebo',
  7: 'correct_placebo_baseline',
  8: 'incorrect_placebo',
  9: '0'},
 'expbin': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 1},
 'value': {0: 31.5,
  1: 10.0,
  2: 21.0,
  3: 22.0,
  4: 8.688,
  5: 20.0,
  6: 37.5,
  7: 12.0,
  8: 32.5,
  9: 10.0}}
```

Comment: can you provide the expected output for clarity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) to get the conditions as columns:

```
df2 = df.pivot(index=['trial_id', 'expbin'], columns='placebovstreatment', values='value')
```

Output:

```
placebovstreatment     0  correct_placebo_baseline  correct_treatment  incorrect_placebo
trial_id expbin                                                                         
1        1          31.5                    10.000               21.0                NaN
2        2          22.0                     8.688                NaN                NaN
3        2           NaN                    20.000                NaN               37.5
4        1           NaN                    12.000                NaN               32.5
5        1          10.0                       NaN                NaN                NaN
```

You can then easily perform computations:

```
df2['correct_treatment'] - df2['correct_placebo_baseline']
```

Output:

```
trial_id  expbin
1         1         11.0
2         2          NaN
3         2          NaN
4         1          NaN
5         1          NaN
dtype: float64
```